# Can a mother cat distinguish among her kittens?

Tags: cats

Can a mother cat distinguish among her kittens?

For example: If she has three kittens can she tell which one is “Kitten 1”?

Same question for the kittens, if they have two siblings can they tell which one is “Sibling 1”?

Comment: Yes she can. She can also tell if the kittens belong to her or if they were born from other cats. They do this using smell, sight and the ways kittens cry out.